# Firebase Firestore set() method not working on Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

When I try to use the set method to add a new document to my firestore database, nothing happens.

```
Future<void> _createUser() async {
    try {
      await Auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassowrd(
        email: _emailController.text,
        password: _passwordController.text,
      );

      final newUser = UserData(
        name: '',
        dateOfBirth: DateTime.now(),
        sex: false,
        location: GeoPoint(0, 0),
        bio: '',
        sportsPlayed: Map(),
        hasSetupAccount: false,
        // profileImage: null,
      );

      final json = newUser.toJson();
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Users')
          .doc(Auth().currentUser!.uid.toString())
          .set(json);
```

Comment: I've tired with an empty map, still didn't work

Comment: "nothing happens" is really hard to help with. Did you try checking of there's an error coming from from the call to `set(json)` - for example by putting an `await` on that statement and then checking if an exception shows up in your `catch` handler.

Comment: try adding await on the FirebaseFirestore.instance and show the catch block result if its throwing and exception.

Comment: Agree with @FrankvanPuffelen  with answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `set(json)` call returns a `Future` and if the call fails, that future is rejected. But your code currently doesn't handle that.

The simplest way to detect such errors is to use `await`, similar to what you already do for `createUserWithEmailAndPassowrd` [sic].

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Users')
      .doc(Auth().currentUser!.uid.toString())
      .set(json);
```

Using `await` translates the failing `Future` into an exception that your existing `catch` block can then handle and display to discover the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Thank you, is it working now! Really appreciate you help